# Blender 2.8: how to cut non visible edges?

Tags: modeling, edges, knife-tool

I'm using the knife tool (shift + spacebar + K)  to cut a cube.

I would like to reach the edges that are behind my current view also.

What is the procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To cut through, press <kbd>Z</kbd> just after you've activated the knife.

And press <kbd>C</kbd> to cut perpendicularly to the view and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> to cut an edge by its center.